# Uisegment buttons over scroll view

Tags: uiscrollview, uisegmentedcontrol

hi iam trying to put a uisegmented controls over a uiscrollview beacuse i want them to scroll horizontally this is the code i tried

```
UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 600, 300)];
scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(500, 50);
scroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
scroll.pagingEnabled = YES;
scroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
scroll.autoresizingMask = YES;
scroll.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
NSArray *itemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"One", @"Two",  @"Three",@"four",@"Five", nil];
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:itemArray];
segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0,10, 500, 50);
segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStylePlain;
segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 4;

[scroll addSubview:segmentedControl];
[self.view addSubview:scroll];
```

any one please help me to accomplish this . thanks in advance happy coding

Answer (score 0):

The frame for the scroll View must be less than the Content size of scroll view. If you will increase your content size definitely it will work. For example:-

```
 UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
    scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(500, 50);
    scroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
    scroll.pagingEnabled = YES;
    scroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
    scroll.autoresizingMask = YES;
    scroll.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
    NSArray *itemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"One", @"Two",  @"Three",@"four",@"Five", nil];


    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:itemArray];
    segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0,10, 500, 50);
    segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStylePlain;
    segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 4;

    [scroll addSubview:segmentedControl];
    [self.view addSubview:scroll];
```

If its supportive please mark the answer correct. Thanks very much.